# How to handle escape character (`) in string under PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, escaping

I am using PowerShell to read a string from and XML file CDATA sectiona and it contains PowerShell esacpe character (`) as part of the string content. When PowerShell is reading and writing this content, it is removing the escape character and it is causing problems in the usage of the same content.

I am not able to add double escape sequence like `` in my input since it is provided by the user and we cannot restrict user for the same.

How to get this processed correctly by PowerShell?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Use single quotes to quote the string. That will keep keep special characters and avoid expanding variables. As long as you use single quotes, PowerShell won't escape anything. `Read-Host` would also creates the string using single quotes. And if you need for some reason really need to escape the escape-chars, you could use `$text = (Read-Host "Test") -replace 'backtick', '2xbacktick'`

Comment: @Graimer, FYI, the string is coming as an input to the script which is provided in XML CDATA section and the PS script gets this in variable content, not in single quotes.

Comment: I still can't reproduce it. See "answer" with proof of what I'm experiencing. Can you provide more information? A sample xml, your code and the output you recieve. It will make this far easier :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce you problem. Need more information.

Test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<exampleOfACDATA>
<![CDATA[
    This is Graimer`s [CDATA[]] test.
    Notice that I just used a backtick in my text,
    which is PowerShell's escape character.
    I'm gonna store this in `$s` in PS.
]]>
</exampleOfACDATA>
```

Powershell

```
PS > $xml = [xml](Get-Content .\Desktop\test.xml)
$s = $xml.exampleOfACDATA."#cdata-section"
$s

    This is Graimer`s [CDATA[]] test.
    Notice that I just used a backtick in my text,
    which is PowerShell's escape character.
    I'm gonna store this in `$s` in PS.
```

In general, to make sure that special characters behave like normal characters, variables don't expand etc., use single quotes `'text'` around your string. This is powershell's normal behaviour when you get strings from other sources(functions, files ...) too.